# Clip off letters instead of words

Tags: html, css

I am making a sort of feed, and names can be up to 32 characters long so I made a max width so it wont get to long. The thing is with my css it clips the last word off if it get longer than the max width, how can I make it clip just the letters off that make it to long?

(Sorry if you run the code it looks a bit different on here)

```css
div.raffleentry {
 width: 100%;
 height: 61px;
 background-color: #6FFF6F;
 border-width: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
 border-color: #8B8B8B;
 border-style: solid;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

p.raffleentry {
 width: 759px;
 height: 61px;
 font-size: 25;
 line-height: 61px;
 float: right;
 background-color: red;
}

span.profilename {
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 61px;
 line-height: 61px;
 max-width: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-align: right;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="raffleentry">
  <p class="raffleentry"><span class="profilename">FaZe Crab OpTic</span></p>
  <img class="profilepic" src="faze crab optic.jpg">
</div>
```

[image]What you see.
[image]Behind the scenes what's actually going on.
[image]What I want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: nowrap;` to `span.profilename` (From W3Schools - Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a 
 tag is encountered)